# Full Text Searching of mysql issue of file uploaded in php mysql

Tags: php

I have a problem in php.I have uploaded a text file in php where each uploaded files contents are insert in different  rows.But the problem is in Searching keywords using full text functionalitnality.Like I got last id by mysql_insert_id.But how to get first id of the first row of files content when I insert a uploaded file 
 and write the simple query for it

```
<?php
    $first_inserted_id=Select last_insert_id();
     $last_id=mysql_insert_id();
    $post_value$ = $_POST['search'];

    while($sql =mysql_query("select * from tbl_name where sentences LIKE '%$post_value$' BETWEEN $first_inserted_id AND $last_id"))
    {
    echo $row['sentences']."\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `last_insert_id()` only works for the CURRENT connection's LAST insert performed. it doesn't work if you did an insert a month ago on some different connection.

Comment: Marc cld you help me if I insert files contents in different rows.how do i get when the inserted rows first id.